Managing multiple MongoDB connections Spring Boot
I have a Spring Boot application, using Spring Data's MongoDB driver. In this application, I want to spin up multiple connections during runtime, execute a query, then maintain a connection for X minutes, before closing it after a period of inactivity.
    private MongoCredential buildCredential(SourceResource source) {
        MongoCredentials sourceCredentials = objectMapper.convertValue(source.getCredentials(), MongoCredentials.class);
        return MongoCredential.createCredential(sourceCredentials.getUsername(), sourceCredentials.getAuthDatabase(), sourceCredentials.getPassword().toCharArray());
    }

    private MongoClient buildClient(SourceResource source) {
        MongoCredentials sourceCredentials = objectMapper.convertValue(source.getCredentials(), MongoCredentials.class);
        return MongoClients.create(
                MongoClientSettings.builder()
                        .applyToClusterSettings(builder ->
                                builder.hosts(Collections.singletonList(new ServerAddress(sourceCredentials.getHost(), sourceCredentials.getPort())))
                        )
                        .credential(buildCredential(source))
                        .build()
        );
    }

    private MongoDatabaseFactory buildFactory(SourceResource source) {
        MongoCredentials sourceCredentials = objectMapper.convertValue(source.getCredentials(), MongoCredentials.class);
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(buildClient(source), sourceCredentials.getDatabase());
    }

    public MongoTemplate connect(SourceResource source) {
        return new MongoTemplate(buildFactory(source));
    }

My question is, what is the best approach to persist this connection for usage in other aspects of the application? Can I serialise and deserialise the object in a Redis cache? I'm not sure.
Then, how do I purge/close the connection after X minutes?
Thanks!
